# Entering into table input caluclates value

Tags: html, jquery, forms

As in when someone inputs to say how many £0.50 coins are in the cash register :

5 coins in cash register and the user inputs 5:

However I need the total to be £0.50 x 5 (x amount of coins entered)

This will be for £0.01 , £0.02, £1.00, £2.00 etc so would be great if it was dynamic and easy to setup for each input field

Thanks :)

Comment: Please review [ask].  You'll need to include quite a bit more information, such as some sample HTML for your table and when you want this to happen.   How far have you managed to get?  Created the table (if yes, include it, or a cut down version at least)?  Triggering an event?  Reading values from inputs?  Setting values into the total (input or cell?)?  Multiplying two values together?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in below snippet :

```js
function TotalAmountCal() {
  var coinNum = document.getElementById('coinNum').value
  var TotalAmount = (coinNum * 0.50)

  document.getElementById('TotalAmount').innerHTML = "£" + TotalAmount
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="coinNumber">£0.50</label>
  <input type="number" name="coinNumber" class="form-control" id="coinNum" oninput="TotalAmountCal();" placeholder="Enter number of coins">
</div>

<div>Total amount present :<span id="TotalAmount"> Enter coins :)</span></div>
```